# Crystal Reports is not pulling the same data as SQL Studio

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I executed a simple SELECT * FROM ABCD in SQL Studio and can see all data. I connected to the exact same table in Crystal reports and it is not pulling anything at all. I can see data in other tables via Crystal. What could be causing this?

Comment: Have you added anything to the report's Select Expert or Selection Formulas that may be filtering the data?  You may also want to export the SQL code from your report and then copy & paste that into your query tool for your database so you can ensure your report is building the query the way you intended.  To export the SQL from your report go to Database on the menu toolbar and then choose Show SQL Query.

Comment: There are about 20,000 NULL values for the field I need in the query tool. At 20,001 the field I need starts populating. I looked at Crystal Reports and it is only pulling the 20,000 NULL values and stops exactly at the 20,0001 record where the data starts populating for the field I need.

Comment: I've seen some posts on the SAP forums that indicate Crystal Reports has a default hard limit of 20,000 records that it can return.  Take a look at this [link](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5060828/crystal-reports-xi-max-records-limit-reached.html) to a question posted on the SAP forums for more information.  If you think this may be your issue, I would recommend reaching out to SAP support for help before changing settings that may impact your entire reporting systems/servers.

Comment: Thank you I opened a case with SAP